# The code works but the output differs by approx. 4.5% from statistically right

Tags: python, distribution

I'm trying to make program from tutorial, details below:

The code suppose to simulate 100 coin tosses by generating a random sequence of T and H characters.
After that it should count how many sub sequences of the same resulting tosses there are in the sequences.
In this specific example I am checking for 6 same resulting tosses in a row.

```
import random

seq_count = 0
for _ in range(1000000):

    random_set = str()

    for toss in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            random_set += "H"
        else:
            random_set += "T"

    count = 1
    last_toss = random_set[0]
    block = False

    for toss in random_set[1:]:
        if toss == "H":
            if last_toss == "H":
                if not block:
                    count += 1
            else:
                count = 1
                block = False
            last_toss = toss
        else:
            if last_toss == "T":
                if not block:
                    count += 1
            else:
                count = 1
                block = False
            last_toss = toss

        if count < 6 or block:
            continue
        else:
            seq_count += 1
            block = True

print(f'{seq_count}')
```

I have tested with various test samples - it seams to be fine, however statistically the distribution suppose to be 1/64 = 0.0156 but in my case it constantly produce the result of 0.0149

Any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Are you correcting for the fact that 100 coin tosses contain only 95 sequences of 6 tosses, not 100? For example, the sequence can start with `random_set[0]` or `random_set[1]` or ... `random_set[94]` but not with `random_set[95]` or anything after.

Comment: If you don't seed your random number generator you'll get the same sequence of random number on every run, so "constantly" makes sense.

Comment: Also if you get 7 in a row, should that count as two 6 in a row?

Comment: @MarkRansom what Python implementation / version is this? In CPython, a trivial script that just does `import random; print(random.random())` gives a different result every  time it is run. Looks like in CPython, the `random` module seeds itself on import based on the system's urandom or on the system clock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817705/pythons-random-what-happens-if-i-dont-use-seedsomevalue

Comment: @slothrop sorry, I must have been thinking of C/C++.

Comment: When you say the result should be 1/64, should it not in fact be 1/32? For a sequence of 6 tosses, there's a 1/64 change that all are heads, and 1/64 they are all tails. The total probability for "6 same tosses" should be 2/64, i.e. 1/32.

Comment: Your odds of getting 6 in a row increase as the total number of trials increases. In 7 flips, for example, you can get `THHHHHH`, `HHHHHHT`, `HHHHHHH`, `HTTTTTT`, `TTTTTTH`, or `TTTTTTT`. That's 6/128 = 3/64 > 1/32. The math gets hairier as the number of trials increases, but the idea stats the same.

Comment: @chepner Right, that's the probability of "at least one run of 6 H or 6 T in a series of N tosses", which does indeed increase with N, and in fact asymptotically approaches 1. I **think** OP is trying to calculate the probability that "a randomly selected sequence of 6 consecutive tosses is all-H or all-T", which is what would be 1/32.